# Concept of research debt in UX design

Tags: user-research, research, consistency, research-debt

It seems like the concept of [tech debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) is very familiar among developers and programmers but when it comes to research we are still struggling to understand how to avoid a similar problem that arises from doing too much research too quickly without having an overall objective and defined process.

Are there other references and case studies about research debt other than what I have seen written in a different [field](https://distill.pub/2017/research-debt/) and my own thoughts on [Medium](https://blog.prototypr.io/reduce-your-research-deficit-5c027dc005a9) (I mean there are but I am not sure where to find them)?

Comment: I think also something I've noticed is UX designers take any form of research as gospel without understanding context and how products vary in need. This could also contribute to research debt. Especially when new findings come out that might "nullify" previous ones.

Comment: If I'm working in for a closed group of users then asking them what they want to see in a new version often only yields an image of what they're currently using. In these cases I will make assumptions about what I think is best practice and go ahead with building a prototype. At this point my assumptions need validation through testing - this validation could be considered "research debt" that needs to be carried out to ensure the product works for it's users.

Comment: What kind of research are you talking about? Some discovery research is done in order to determine overall objective and process.

Comment: @AndrewMartin, that's why we don't ever ask users what they want. I've found it to be more useful to observe users' current processes, goals, and tasks and design to support them.

Comment: @KenMohnkern perhaps I explained myself in the wrong way - I was talking about researching user needs. For a product with a closed user group (like an in house staffing system for instance) it's difficult to research user needs without ending up with an outline for a product that just reflects the current working patterns regardless of how broken those patterns may be.

Comment: @AndrewMartin, thanks for the clarification. I work on an internal system too, and we do shadowing sessions where we pay attention to users' complete process, even outside of the use of our system. (What other systems do they use? What do they google? What do they write down?) It's pretty revealing and helps us decide what new features would be actually useful.

Comment: @KenMohnkern Does it matter what type of research that is involved? I think that you can incur research debt regardless of the type of research you are doing if not done correctly.

Comment: The first question in research is "So what is the question?".  It's very easy to blow a lot of budget collecting data, which is interesting, but doesn't answer the right question.

Comment: @PhillipW I totally agree, and am a little surprised that not more thought is given to this, but then also not so surprised as there is a lot of market/business driven type of research that results in potential research debt.

Answer (score 11):

To understand debt in UX research, please take a look to some detailed articles about UX debt. I liked this explanation of UX debt, found on "[The 3-Step Guide to Erasing Your UX Debt](https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/3-step-guide-erasing-ux-debt/)":

> If your product suffers from inconsistent behavior or performance,
>   you’ve probably made long-term sacrifices for short-term gains. You’ve
>   accumulated UX debt.
>
> When it comes to UX debt, you won’t know all the answers immediately.
>   And you probably won’t fix it all by the next release. But that
>   doesn’t mean you should give up. If you can create a plan that doesn’t
>   give product management a heart attack, you will eventually eliminate
>   your debt.

Another article about UX debt that has some good points is [Juggling Growth and Usability: A UX Debt Primer](https://medium.com/@johnpcutler/juggling-growth-and-usability-a-ux-debt-primer-af92d7a08c35).

Other resources:

- [Making Good On Your UX Debt](https://www.usertesting.com/blog/2015/10/26/ux-debt/)
- [User Experience Debt: Creating awareness and acting on missed opportunities.](https://www.slideshare.net/andr3wjwright/ias14-uxdebt/13-IA_Summit_March_30_2014)
- [UX Debt in the Enterprise: A Practical Approach](http://uxpamagazine.org/ux-debt-in-the-enterprise/)

[image: UX debt] - image from [UX Debt in the Enterprise: A Practical Approach](https://www.usertesting.com/blog/2015/10/26/ux-debt/)

[image]

- Table from http://uxpamagazine.org/ux-debt-in-the-enterprise/

Update: A New article that could help, on Nielsen Norman Group:
[UX Debt: How to Identify, Prioritize, and Resolve](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ux-debt/)

Comment: +1 I am more interested in the research debt incurred in most of the UX related projects I have been involved in rather than UX debt because it encompasses issues with research, design, prototyping and testing so it's not an easy topic to cover. However, these are good references and I will have to look :)